# Rules for limits equalities in relation to squaring

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I currently have the equation:

$ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(X_{n+1}) = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(X_n)^2 $

I am simply looking for just the limit of $X_n$ so can I simply square both sides and have:

$ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(X_n) = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{X_{n+1}}) $

Thanks to whoever can clarify this for me!

EDIT:
Sorry guys, formatting is fixed now, it's a recursive sequence.

Comment: Do you mean $x_{n+1}$ or $x_n+1$?

Comment: You mean "take square toots pf both sides", not "square both sides", right?  You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format posts on this site.

Comment: Format is fixed now, any clarification would be great!

Comment: Any 2nd root of itself would be a solution. You could have $0,1$, an identity matrix. $\epsilon_0$ might work too. (not sure about that last one).

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do that but there is no reason to- changing from the square to the square root doesn't help.  If this sequence converges, let X be the limit.  Then taking the limit as n goes to infinity of both sides gives $X= X^2$ so that $X^2- X= X(X-1)= 0$, either X= 0 or X= 1.  **Whether** the sequence converges and, if so, which of those is the limit depends on what the initial value is.  Obviously if $X_0= 0$, the sequence is 0, 0, 0, ..., which converges to 0 while if $X_0= 1$, the sequence is 1, 1, 1,..., which converges to 1.  In fact if is not difficult to see if $|X_0|> 1$, the sequence does not converge, if $|X_0|= 1$ the sequence converges to 1, and if $|X_0|< 1$ the sequence converges to 0.